# How to define a C dataype using structure to store a rational number( fraction of two numbers)?

Tags: c, structure

How to define a C datatype using structure to store a rational number (fraction of two numbers).

Comment: `struct rational_num{ int numerator; int denominator };`

Answer (score 2):

As I have mentioned in my comment you can create structure to store a rational number in these way:

1) **Declaring Structure**

```
struct rational_num
{ 
    int numerator; 
    int denominator; 
};
```

To create a variable you need to use `struct rational_num r1;`

2) **Using typedef with Structure**

```
typedef struct 
{ 
    int numerator; 
    int denominator; 
} rational_num;
```

To create a variable you need to use `rational_num r1;`

Answer (score 1):

you can simply define it as a `struct`:

```
struct Rational
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};
```